# Can't acces a postgresql table

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2, digital-ocean

Simple queries run for hours, but only for one table, what can be the cause?

I tried deleting it, obviously it got stalled too, and I can't do any other basic or complex queries for that table. I am at digitalocean, so I can't just do a restart on the DB.
I imported this table from a URL with python and I forgot to close the psycopg2 connection before running the script so I had to terminate it, and maybe that could have caused the problem.

BTW. this is my personal database, I don't have other admins who could have locked me out or anything.
I also looked at the logs, but there isn't any sign of unusual activities.
Here is it though, originally its in German, I had to translate it.

09:18:35.644: PostgreSQL 14.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit launches

09:18:35.645: expected connections on IPv6 address "::", port 25060

09:18:35.645: expecting connections on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 25060

09:18:35.691: database system was interrupted; last known action on 2022-06-16 23:54:18 CEST

09:18:36.137: database system was not shut down properly; automatic
recovery in progress

09:18:36.140: Redo starts at 0/172B560

09:18:36.141: invalid record length at 0/172B598: 24 expected, 0 received

09:18:36.141: redo complete at 0/172B560 System usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s,
elapsed: 0.00 s

09:18:36.164: database system is ready to accept connections

20:34:07.203: fast shutdown requested

20:34:07.208: any active transactions are aborted

20:34:07.232: background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 15088) terminated with status 1

20:34:07.241: shut down

20:34:07.292: database system shut down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have an orphaned idle process that has acquired a [lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) on the table which has not been released due to an uncommitted transaction -and will never be released since you have no ability to commit it.

If simple queries like `SELECT * FROM table` are blocking, you most likely have an `Access Exclusive Lock` on the table from something like an `ALTER`/`DROP` statement that had run in the script that you cancelled.

You can verify this by running:

```sql
SELECT
    psa.pid,
    psa.query,
    psa.state,
    pg_locks.mode lock_mode,
    relation::regclass locked_relation

FROM
  pg_locks
  JOIN pg_stat_activity psa on pg_locks.pid = psa.pid

WHERE
  granted
  and 'my_schema.my_table'::regclass = relation
```

Then you can kill any process that has a lock on your table:

```sql
SELECT
    pg_terminate_backend(psa.pid),

FROM
  pg_locks
  JOIN pg_stat_activity psa on pg_locks.pid = psa.pid

WHERE
  granted
  and 'my_schema.my_table'::regclass = relation
```

If you still have blocked queries, you can open a new connection while the blocked query is running, and execute the following:

```sql
SELECT
    activity.pid pid,
    activity.state state,
    activity.query blocked_query,
    blocking_pid,
    blocking_activity.state blocking_state,
    blocking_activity.query blocking_query,
    locks.locked_relations blocking_relation_locks
FROM
 pg_stat_activity activity
 JOIN LATERAL unnest(pg_blocking_pids(activity.pid)) blocking_pids(blocking_pid) ON TRUE
 JOIN pg_stat_activity blocking_activity ON (blocking_pids.blocking_pid = blocking_activity.pid)
 JOIN LATERAL (
     SELECT
        string_agg(locks.relation::regclass::text,',') locked_relations
     FROM

       pg_locks locks

     WHERE
         locks.pid = blocking_pid

     GROUP BY
       blocking_pid
) locks ON TRUE;
```

This will show you every process that is blocking another process. Once you find the offending processes you can exterminate them using `pg_terminate_backend(pid)`

If you want to kill every pid blocking another pid, you can run:

```sql
SELECT 
  pg_terminate_backend(unnest(pg_blocking_pids(pid)))
FROM
  pg_stat_activity
```

If don't have other critical processes running and want to eliminate every single database connection for the sake of simplicity, do:

```sql
SELECT
  pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM
  pg_stat_activity
WHERE
  --delete this line if you want to kill all connections on the whole cluster
  pg_stat_activity.datname = '<your database name>'
  AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Once complete, you'll only have the connection on which you executed this query.

If none of the above steps work it's possible -as Laurenz Albe pointed out in the comments -that you may have a [prepared transaction](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/prepared-transactions/) that is locking your table. The locks that a prepared transaction creates can survive backend terminations -and even server restarts. They must be explicitly rolled back or committed.

You can check if a prepared transaction is locking any of your tables with the following query

```sql
SELECT
  ptx.transaction prep_tx_id,
  ptx.gid prep_tx_name,
  locks.mode lock_mode,
  locks.relation::regclass locked_relation
FROM
  pg_prepared_xacts ptx
  JOIN pg_locks tx ON ptx.transaction = tx.transactionid and tx.locktype = 'transactionid'
  JOIN pg_locks locks ON tx.virtualtransaction = locks.virtualtransaction

WHERE
  locks.granted
  and locks.relation = 'my_schema.my_table'::regclass
```

You can then rollback the prepared transaction like:

```sql
ROLLBACK PREPARED '<TRANSACTION_NAME>'
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added a section on prepared transactions to my answer, thanks for pointing this out!